# MATLAB Perceptron

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I cant seem to figure out why I have a high percentage error.

I'm trying to get a perceptron between X1 and X2 which are Gaussian distributed data sets with distinct means and identical co-variances.

Below is my code:

```
N=200;
C= [2 1; 1 2]; %Covariance
m1=[0 2];
m2=[1.5 0];%mean
X1 = mvnrnd(m1, C, N/2);
X2 = mvnrnd(m2, C, N/2);

X = [X1; X2];
X = [X ones(N,1)]; %bias
y = [-1*ones(N/2,1); ones(N/2,1)]; %classification

%Split data into training and test 
ii = randperm(N);
Xtr = X(ii(1:N/2),:);
ytr = X(ii(1:N/2),:);
Xts = X(ii(N/2+1:N),:);
yts = y(ii(N/2+1:N),:);
Nts = N/2;

w = randn(3,1);
eta = 0.001;
%learn from training set
for iter=1:500 
j = ceil(rand*N/2);
if( ytr(j)*Xtr(j,:)*w < 0)
w = w + eta*Xtr(j,:)'; 
end
end

%apply what you have learnt to test set
yhts = Xts * w;
disp([yts yhts])
PercentageError = 100*sum(yts .*yhts < 0)/Nts;
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I address this challenge?

Comment: I think you should explain the essence of what you are trying to do, and what you have investigated already. "What's wrong with this code" questions aren't that suitable for StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

You are altering weights in the wrong direction for the negative cases.

The line

```
w = w + eta*Xtr(j,:)';
```

should be

```
w = w + eta*Xtr(j,:)'*ytr(j);
```

With that change I got 12% error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is wrong:

```
ytr = X(ii(1:N/2),:);
```

ytr should be the label of the training data. In this case, it should be

```
ytr = y(ii(1:N/2),:);
```